# searching multiple words from dict and creating null entry check

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find a way to return a sentence based upon the input of the user i.e key word search.

I have a dictionary created and can return a sentence based on one word but cant figure out if I can return a sentence based on multiple words:

**water** damage returns a sentence on dropping your phone into water
i have a **cracked screen** does not return anything. I am aware that the issue is around the .split.strip functions I am using.

My next issue is that I can not seem to create a null entry check, I have tried the usual, while input_1 is None, or =='' yet the strip function removes whitespace so I am guessing there is no null entry to pick up on.

```
similar_words = {
    'water': 'you have let water into your phone',
    'wet': 'let your phone dry out then try to restrat the phone',
    'crack case': 'you have cracked your screen or case, this will need replacing by a specialist',
    'cracked screen': 'you have cracked your screen or case, this will need replacing by a specialist',
    'turn on': 'your battery may need replacing',
    'crack': 'your phone screen has been cracked, you need to contact the technician centre',

}


def check():
    if word.lower() in similar_words:
        print(similar_words[word.lower()])

input_1 = input("What seems to be the problem with your phone?: ").strip().split()

for word in input_1:
    check()

def close():
    print ('Please press enter to close the program')
    quit()

close_1 = input('Have we addressed your problem, please answer yes or no?: ')
if close_1=='yes':
    close()
else:
    print ('Lets us move on then')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is simply "cracked screen" then the call to `split()` returns a list of two words: `["cracked", "screen"]`. The test `word.lower() in similar_words` effectively compares each word to all of the keys of the dictionary looking for a match.

As you have neither "cracked" nor "screen" as a key in the dictionary, it fails to find a match.

Each of your keys needs to be a single word if you are splitting your input to a list of single words.

But then, if you have "cracked" as a key, an input such as "my case cover is cracked" will be reported as if it was a cracked screen.

You need a much smarter test, and probably need to read up on ngrams. Split the input into unigrams, bigrams, etc, and check each against the list of keys. Then you need to figure out how to deal with inputs like "my screen is cracked".

As for the NULL check, if the input string is empty, `strip().split()` will return an empty list (`[]`). Check for `len(input_1) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your program I think that you need to display the phone problem's solution only but your program is not displaying it. So I have done some changes in the program and it is displaying it.

```
similar_words = {
'water': 'you have let water into your phone',
'wet': 'let your phone dry out then try to restart the phone',
'crack case' : 'you have cracked your screen or case, this will need replacing by a specialist',
'cracked screen' : 'you have cracked your screen or case, this will need replacing by a specialist',
'turn on' : 'your battery may need replacing',
'crack' : 'your phone screen has been cracked, you need to contact the technician centre'
}

input_1 = input("What seems to be the problem with your phone?: ").split()
    for word in input_1:
        if word in similar_words.keys():
        print(similar_words[word])
        #similar_words[word] gives only the value of the key word

close_1 = input('Have we addressed your problem, please answer yes or no?: ')
if close_1=='yes':
    quit()
else:
    print ('Lets us move on then')
```